# Installation problems on magento 2.2.0

Tags: installation, magento2.2.0

I tried to install the latest version of magento 2.2.0 on wamp server 32 bit on my laptop. During the chceking readying process it shows missing .intl files . I tried looking for help on youtube and did the correction on php.ini removed the coloum before this file saved and restarted the wamp and still it showing the same error message enclosing is screen shot of the errors.

I am using Wamp server 32 bit 
Apache 2.4.27
PHP 7.1.9
MYSQL 5.7.19
Maria DB 10.2.8

I am using windows 7 Ultimatum 32 bit 4gb ram I7 intel processor

Can you please help me fix this error by remotely using tieam viewer or step by steps.

Thanking you

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Enable PHP Intl extention and restart your wamp. It will be fixed then.

Answer (score 1):

Please just edit your php.ini file
search for below line in php.ini
extension=php_intl.dll

if you find it like ';extension=php_intl.dll' than just remove ';' from the line and restart wamp server.

if not found a  line than add it into the php.ini file.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please, go wamp/php/php.ini and edit uncomment module/extension called: from `;extension=php_intl.dll` to `extension=php_intl.dll`

restart apache server.